# ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi-env.properties does not get populated to the flow

Tags: environment-variables, apache-nifi, populate

I'm using nifi 1.21.0
I defined env vars in ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi-env.properties

However these env vars do not get populated to the flow.

```
root@nifi-76b6b75894-nmg2j:/opt/nifi/conf# grep -i sftp ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/nifi-env.properties
SFTP_PPK=/data/nifi/keys/sftp-private-key.ppk
sftphost=sftp.server.com
sftpuser=sftpuser
```

And I'm expecting to see these env vars on nifo canvas variables but I see none:
[image]

Does anyone know what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what is `nifi-env.properties` ? why do you think it should affect variables in nifi ?

Comment: @daggett  I was mistaken about the  variables. nifi-env.properties is what's referred by nifi.variable.registry.properties= in nifi.properties file.  what's defined in the file located at nifi.varible.registry.properties can be used as env var (${variable_name})  in processors.  Is there a way to check the variable name and value populated to flow from nivi.variable.registry.properties? Thanks.

Comment: just believe in this ;) because it's a basic functionality. or create a simple sub-flow `GenerateFlowfile->LogAttributes` and in generate flowfile define parameters with `${...}` values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help from @daggett

It's basically about variables defined in an external file specified by nifi.variable.registry.properties.
There's no straightforward way to verify the values populated to nifi flow.
Not as simple as what you manually defined as variables inside the flow.